# Ubuntu won't work after turning off from pressing the power button

Tags: boot, power-management

My computer went to sleep mode after a period of inactivity. When I went back, I inputted my password, but it was taking too long to load, so I became inpatient and turned off directly from pressing the power on button. When I turned it back on, it only shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbfmL.jpg) and it won't do anything else. Could anyone please help? I'm losing my head because this is the only device I have to do all my homework due on 2 days :(

For the record, my PC only has Ubuntu, not dual boot or any other additional OS

System information:
Ubuntu 23.10
Acer

These error messages appear a bunch of times: "Failed to start gdm.service - GNOME display manager" or "Gdm: GemSession: no session desktop files installed, aborting..."

Comment: It might be checking disks (it is running fsck). Please wait up to 1 hour

Comment: If it's still work, does the TTY work with Ctrl+Alt+F3?

Comment: You've not said what Ubuntu product & release of that product you're asking about, but if I'm impatient with a system, I'll never use the power button to force shutdown & thus risk a disk issue that needs to be resolved prior to normal boot (*which is likely your issue; have you explored this due to power outage which occurred when you forced power off*)... I tell the kernel to safely turn off or reboot (ie. SysRq command direct to Linux kernel; bypassing any stuck GUI/UI on the device). I'd suggest boot *live* and checking your file-systems using appropriate commands (`fsck`. `xfs_check` etc)

Comment: @DanielT It's been 4 hours. The TTY seems to be working properly, I can log in, but I honestly don't know what to do there, I'm fairly new to all of this to be honest.

Comment: Getting to the TTY means it's no longer fscking. You can run `sudo systemctl restart gdm3` to restart the GUI. If that doesn't work, remove or reinstall any Nvidia drivers. Also look in `dmesg` and `journalctl -r` for any errors. For you homework, I recommend `cp`ing it to a USB drive to back up

Comment: @guiverc Should I force shutdown from pressing the button again and then booting live? What should I do after checking my files? I'm freaking out pls help 

Comment: @DanielT I ran "sudo systemctl restart gdm3", then reinstalled Nvidia drivers, and then rebooted. Still not working. dmesg doesn't seem to be working "dmsg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted" aaand I don't really know what to look for from the other command's output. I appreciate your help

Comment: Use `sudo` in front of dmesg and journalctl. You can also plug in the LiveCD, open the disk with your files, and do the homework there

Comment: @DanielT there seems to be a problem with the "gdm" service. These error messages appear a bunch of times: "Failed to start gdm.service - GNOME display manager" or "Gdm: GemSession: no session desktop files installed, aborting..."

Comment: `sudo apt reinstall ubuntu-desktop ; sudo apt reinstall ubuntu-session`

Comment: @DanielT Ohhh man thank you so much, you are a hero  I don't have enough words for how thankful I am

Comment: Ok, I will make this into an answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `no session desktop files installed`. To get the desktop sessions back, you can run the following:

```bash
sudo apt reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt reinstall ubuntu-session
```

I found the `ubuntu-session` package to reinstall by searching with `dpkg -S /usr/share/wayland-sessions xsessions`. I also put the `ubuntu-desktop` to reinstall because it's often suggested. Power loss during your work shouldn't cause these to become uninstalled, but perhaps there was a background update that got interrupted.

Comment: You can try to type "startx" and "xinit". If it fails please post the error messages here.

Comment: @AlainReve Ubuntu 23.10 does not use X11. And I think this answer already solves the problem because of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1506340/ubuntu-wont-work-after-turning-off-from-pressing-the-power-button/1506362?noredirect=1#comment2642587_1506340